# How to say if x > x + y after z seconds:?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function, contMove(), that continuously moves an object across a tkinter window when I click a button. However, if I click the button that runs this function more than once, it speeds up, as the first subroutine hasn't closed, because I want it to run continuously, and they run over the top of eachother, speeding up the movement. I don't want it to speed up, so I want to put in a check that tests whether the X or Y co-ordinate that is being changed, has increased by more than the speed I want it to and if so, kill the subroutine. This seems like it would be a common thing but everything I can find about the time module is either about date and clock time or uses time.sleep, but I can't use that because I can't stop the movement. Sorry if I messed up the formatting of my code when I put it here

```
def contMove(moving):
    global a
    global b  
    global X, Y
    if moving:
        a = a + X
        b = b + Y
        mover.place(x = a, y = b)
        a, b, X, Y = edgeBounce(a, b, X, Y)
        mover.place(x = a, y = b)
        #would be here
        mover.after(17, lambda: contMove(moving))
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Change your call to `after` to look like this and see if it helps: `mover.after(17, contMove, moving)`.

Comment: I'm confused, could you put that in? I don't really know what or where you mean

Comment: remove `mover.after(17, lambda: contMove(moving))`, and replace it with `mover.after(17, contMove, moving)`.

Comment: Ok, it still works, but I don't know what difference it makes

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you are using `after`. The way you are currently using it, the `after` command will look up the value of `moving` only when the `after` command actually runs the command. Therefore, if the value changes between the time you call `after` and the time that `after` calls the function, you will get the most recent version.

What you want instead is to give the value to `after` right away, so that it doesn't have to look up the value at the time that it runs the function. Fortunately `after` lets you supply positional arguments that get passed along to the function.

To fix your code, remove this line:

```
mover.after(17, lambda: contMove(moving))
```

... and replace it with this line:

```
mover.after(17, contMove, moving)
```

Comment: What you told me didn't change anything, In the end I figured out I just needed to use .after_cancel at the beginning of my subroutine.